# Run script in Rails console and have access to objects created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-console

I recently found you can run an arbitrary Ruby file in the Rails console using load or require, as in:

```
load 'test_code.rb'
```

This is great as far as it goes, but using either load or require (what's the difference?) I don't seem to have access to the objects created in the script after it completes.

For example, in my script I might have something like:

```
u = User.where('last_name = ?', 'Spock').first
```

If I start rails console and run that script using load or require, I see it working, I see the query happen, and I can 'put' attributes from the object inside the script and see them in the console output. But once the script is done, the variable u is undefined.

I'd like to run some code to set up a few objects and then explore them interactively. Can this be done? Am I doing something wrong or missing something obvious?

Comment: `load` will include and execute the code from the file every time it is called, whereas `require` will only include it once and only once in an execution thread.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Variables defined in your script will go out of scope once the file is loaded. If you want to use the variables in console, define them as instance variables or constants

```
@u = User.where('last_name = ?', 'Spock').first
```

or

```
USER = User.where('last_name = ?', 'Spock').first
```

Comment: Also equivalent is: `User.find_by(last_name: 'Spock')` (also find the first record) but shorter

Comment: Thanks to you both. Vimsha: I knew I was missing something obvious! This will save me a lot of time. itsnikolay: You learn something new every day!

Answer (score 4):

As explained in http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-load:

> In no circumstance will any local variables in the loaded file be propagated to the loading environment.

An option is to eval the file:

```
eval(File.read 'your_script.rb')
```

and the local variables will be there afterwards.

Comment: I don't see any local variables after the `eval` command. The only accessible variables are instance variables or constants.

Comment: @ThanasisPetsas hi, consider looking for a related question/asking it and linking to it :-)

Comment: in my reading, that quote you provided is only for the circumstance that wrap is true.